# How to disable ListView footer bounce effect

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView that has a footer at the bottom and that ListView Items has an image and a textview. My problem is that when I scroll the list fast to the bottom i.e., to the last item it shows the footer for a while and after that it bring down the footer and shows the last element of the list at the bottom. But whenever I scroll slowly it does not do that like in fast scroll. It just like a bounce effect, on fast scroll the list goes up and after that it comes back showing the last item at the bottom instead of footerview.
I have two images from which one can understand the real scenario.

This is the first image where I have scrolled the list fast and at first I have seen the footer button

[image]

And this is the second image when the scroll is end and the footer button goes down where the last item takes it's place. But this does not happens when I scroll slow. So please help me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]

This is my adapter code

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    Object user;
    ImageDownloader downloader;
    ArrayList<MyCustomAList> list;
    public customAdapter(Context context , int resid , String[] array, Object u, ArrayList<MyCustomAList> list) 
    {
        super(context,resid,array);
        this.context = context;
        this.user = u;
        this.downloader=new ImageDownloader();
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            holder.userImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(list.get(position).text);
        downloader.download(list.get(position).url, holder.userImage);
        return view;
    }


    class ViewHolder 
    {
        ImageView userImage;
        TextView title;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

make the `Layout` which consist the `ListView` and `Footer` like this I think it will solve ur problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- For header portion -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </FrameLayout>
<!-- ListView -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
<!-- Footer -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Footer Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```